# Progress OpenEdge (PROENV) commands to check Server usage (ODBC Connection rejected by OpenEdge Broker)

Tags: sql-server, odbc, openedge, progress-db

Can someone please assist me by explaining the commands to show the number of servers availble for a OpenEdge DB in PROENV.

Online documentations seems to be far and wide.

Problem is I'm trying to connect to OpenEdge DB via a ODBC but one of our OpenEdge DBs rejects the connection via ODBC stating (OpenEdge Broker Rejects the connection).

I'm presuming there are no SQL Servers available(openedge _mprosrv.exe), so the next step would be to check what is available/inuse - hence the question for the PROENV command.

Please note 3 out of 4 of our connections are through a  MS SQL Server Server Linked Object (using the ODBC connection System DSN) - its just the final remaining OpenEdge DB with the broker is rejecting.

Thanks,

Richard

Comment: What is the specific error? ODBC connections require the database name used in the connection to exactly match the name used to start the db server - including case. If you try to connect to 'dbname' when it was served as 'DbName' - it won't work.

Comment: Ive checked that and it matches case to case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to look at PROMON in PROENV, specifically PROMON  > R&D > Option 1 (Status Display) > Option 3 (Servers).

I'd also like to ask if you started the secondary broker for an SQL server type. If you are trying to connect to a 4GL broker with an SQL connection or vice-versa, the connection will be rejected.

Answer (score 0):

From PROENV use "PROMON dbname" to start PROMON.  Then go to the R&D menu (type R&D), and look at options 3 & 17 to see what is going on with servers.

You can also glean useful information from looking at the parameters that were used at db startup.  Open dbname.lg with a text editor and find the last (333) message.  This is the most recent db startup.  The next 50 to 75 lines list the parameters and settings that were actually used.  You are interested in settings related to -Mn, -Ma, -Mpb, -Mi and -S.